# How to structure Rails app where calendar date is the main view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a booking system, I want to create a "per-date" view where the user will see available/unavailable thingamabobs for that particular day (with an option to book one themselves). I am not sure on how I should tackle it in a RoR way.

- Should I create a `Date` model? I guess not, since I don't want to create a database entry for each and every date, that sounds plainly wrong.

  - Or should I create a model, but do not derive it from an `ActiveRecord`? Is that common to have models without corresponding database tables?
- Should I start with a view? If yes, is it going to be a `date.html.erb` view, or something else, since there won't be a `Date` model? What about the controller?
- Or is there something else that should be done to make it work?

Comment: But I want the users to be able to move around the whole calendar day by day -- my understanding is that I would need to create database entries for 365 x num of years I want to include in my app, just to display those later in views. I don't need a "dates" table in my database with each record being a separate date.

Comment: “Then don’t” — what should I do instead? This is exactly why I asked this question.